google shows ad images as featured image in SERP
I am displaying advertisements above articles in the mobile version of my site. However, Google keeps showing those advertisements in the search engine results page (SERP) as article images. Could you please advise me on how to resolve this issue?



This question is similar to: Prevent search engines from indexing specific images on a page. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
